# How could I test C++ compilation on Windows using a Mac OS?

Tags: windows, mac, c++

I'm easily able to check how C++ code compiles on Mac OS and Linux.

However, it's always a guessing game with Windows, as I don't have any Windows OS nearby.

Are there options for developers to check compilation on a Windows command line?

I was going to use Docker, but it appears extremely complicated, given my OS is Mac: https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Mac-based virtual machine.

Parallels or VMWare Fusion are perfectly capable of running any Windows, Mac or nix OS.

VMWare have recently released a free [for personal use] version of Fusion - see https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/fusion-evaluation.html You need to sign up.

Comment: Thank you for the help, VMWare Fusion worked great!